# Convergence of series. Root test didnt work

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

1) $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k^{1/k}-1)^k$

2) $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (1+1/k)^{-k}$

I tried to do the root test for both of these but for the first one I'm not sure what the final limit is and for the last one I get 1 so the root test in inconclusive. How should I do this?

Answer (score 2):

For the first, double-check that root test.  Note that $1/k \to 0$.

For the second, it suffices to note that
$$
\lim_{k \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{k} \right)^{-k} \neq 0
$$
In fact, you should find (using, for instance, L'Hôpital's rule on the log of the limit) that the limit is $e^{-1}$. *(We could also have used the root test here)*

Answer (score 0):

For 1), note that for a fixed $k>1$, the map $x\mapsto x^{1/k}$ is monotone increasing, so $k^{1/k}>1^{1/k}=1$. Moreover, $k^{1/k}=e^{(\log k)/k}$ and $\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{\log k}k=0$, so $\lim_{k\to\infty}k^{1/k}=1$. So given $\rho\in(0,1)$ we may choose $N$ such that $k^{1/k}-1<\rho$ for $k\geqslant N$, and convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(k^{1/k}-1\right)^k$ follows from comparison with the geometric series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \rho^k$.

For 2), it is clear that $1+1/k>1$ for all $k$, so $(1+1/k)^{-k}>1$ and therefore $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (1+1/k)^{-k}=+\infty$.